# How to connect android view to XML view programatically?

Tags: java, android

Here's y custom `GLSurfaceView`:

```
public class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
```

Normally I'd create my custom view by doing:

```
<MyGLSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/glsurfaceview1"
        android:layout_width="640px"
        android:layout_height="480px"
        />
```

But I want to create it through code, not through XML. So which XML item I must put on my XML? Perhaps

```
<SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/glsurfaceview1"
            android:layout_width="640px"
            android:layout_height="480px"
            />
```

?

But then how do I set my `GlSurfaceView` to appear on this XML item? How do I connect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

Add FrameLayout to xml file and in code do something like this:

```
    MyGlSurfaceView mySurfaceView = ...

    FrameLayout frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);
    frameLayout.addView(mySurfaceView);
```